# Multiple adverbs modifying same thing

Tags: verbos, sustantivos, adjetivos, adverbios

If you have multiple adverbs modifying the same noun, verb, or adjective in Spanish, in what order and where do you place the adverbs?

Comment: Welcome to the site, KawaiiKiwi. Would you mind to add an example in your question (even if you think it's wrong)?

Comment: Note that adverbs do not usually modify nouns.

Comment: an adverb never modifies a noun, that’s an adjective.

Comment: You need to provide an example. Otherwise, it's a fool's errand.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the *mente* is added only to the second (or final) adverb in a string, as discussed in [this blog post](https://blog.lengua-e.com/2012/coordinacion-de-adverbios-en-mente/).

This applies to [two adverbs in a row](https://books.google.com/books?id=xGZghb0TeKYC&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=%22lenta+y+eficazmente%22&source=bl&ots=9Ty3nAUKrV&sig=ACfU3U3jFGrmBjO5faKYGqHxuaIA2xOisw&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsh6SGiuvpAhUDYawKHcdhDAQQ6AEwA3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22lenta%20y%20eficazmente%22&f=false)

> Durante el siglo XIX los Estados Unidos más que cuadruplican su territorio, se sigue con "la institución peculiar" en el Sur y se prosigue, lenta y eficazmente, con el genocidio indio y la gloriosa expansión hacia el legendario Oeste americano.

I suppose this would work for three or more adverbs, but such a situation does not appear to be very common.

As noted in the article, one can even separate the adverbs, e.g. "no lenta sino rápidamente."